# how to convert openssl encrypt and decrypt into php

Tags: encryption, openssl, php-7.4

I am trying to convert the following shell commands into php but I ma not getting correct results

```
$key = 'my_key';

    $cmd = "echo -n $plaintext| openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -k $key -md md5";
    $exec = exec($cmd, $output, $status);
    return $status == 0 ? $output[0] : null;
```

the above works in php7.4. I have tried the following

```
$key = "my_key";
    echo "key: $key\n";
    //$key = password_hash($key, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);
    //echo "key: $key\n";
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, null, 'UqA8Z5ztUYnWhnUE');
    echo "ciphertext: $ciphertext\n";
    echo "merged: $key$ciphertext\n";
    return $key . $ciphertext;
```

This is not working. The `key` is supplied by 3rd party

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following

create a key and iv

```
# openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -k hello-aes -P -md md5                                       *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
key=C639A572E14D5075C526FDDD43E4ECF6B095EA17783D32EF3D2710AF9F359DD4
iv =D09A4D2C5DC39843FE075313A7EF2F4C
```

on cli I can use the key to encrypt and decrypt

encrypt

```
# echo -n email@gmail.com | openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -a -k C639A572E14D5075C526FDDD43E4ECF6B095EA17783D32EF3D2710AF9F359DD4 -md md5
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
U2FsdGVkX1+GpDPQ5uLeXlZL9CEgKaBDgDuwvf00m9U=
```

decrypt

```
# echo U2FsdGVkX1+GpDPQ5uLeXlZL9CEgKaBDgDuwvf00m9U= | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -k C639A572E14D5075C526FDDD43E4ECF6B095EA17783D32EF3D2710AF9F359DD4 -md md5
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
email@gmail.com
```

In PhP

I use the `key` and `iv` I created from cli. the `key` is provided to me i do not get to generate this

```
function encryptAES256CBC(string $plaintext): string
{
    $key = 'C639A572E14D5075C526FDDD43E4ECF6B095EA17783D32EF3D2710AF9F359DD4';
    //echo "key hex2bin ". md5($key) . "\n\n";
    $iv = hex2bin('D09A4D2C5DC39843FE075313A7EF2F4C');
    echo "key: $key\n";
    $cipher="aes-256-cbc";

    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);//, null, 'UqA8Z5ztUYnWhnUE');
   
    echo "ciphertext_raw: $ciphertext_raw\n";

    echo "base64_encode: ".base64_encode($ciphertext_raw)."\n";
    echo "base64_encode md5: ".md5(base64_encode($ciphertext_raw))."\n";
    echo "md5: ".md5($ciphertext_raw)."\n";
    return md5($ciphertext_raw);
    return $key . $ciphertext_raw;
}
```

I tried to decode the above output on cli to check it works but it does not. i get error `bad magic number`

output

```
key: C639A572E14D5075C526FDDD43E4ECF6B095EA17783D32EF3D2710AF9F359DD4
ciphertext_raw: y▒▒yV▒ύ2▒G▒▒▒¤▒!▒▒▒%▒"ҋ~▒
base64_encode: B3n1+XlWtM+NMrlHue8R28KkmiG8tpUl/Iwi0ot+vg4=
base64_encode md5: f65b8e0ed4fc86d4b405d37a57bcd6e5
md5: 14e9f14ee94a2c34e52ad80e3f300d40



DECRYPT 14e9f14ee94a2c34e52ad80e3f300d40
 [12:27:43] Destructor
root@0ea89b7ad9df:/# echo 14e9f14ee94a2c34e52ad80e3f300d40 | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -k C639A572E14D5075C526FDDD43E4ECF6B095EA17783D32EF3D2710AF9F359DD4 -md md5
bad magic number
```

UPDATE

I have managed to get decypt working but encrypt not working

this is what I have

```
$passphrase = 'random';
        $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
        $keyData = self::evpBytesToKey($salt, $passphrase);
        $key = substr($keyData, 0, 32);
        $iv = substr($keyData, 32, 16);
        $method = 'AES-256-CBC';

        $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        echo "ciphertext_raw: $ciphertext_raw\n";

        echo "base64_encode: ".base64_encode($ciphertext_raw)."\n";
        echo "base64_encode md5: ".md5(base64_encode($ciphertext_raw))."\n";
        echo "md5: ".md5($ciphertext_raw)."\n";
        echo "merged: ".base64_encode($iv.$ciphertext_raw)."\n";
        return md5($ciphertext_raw);

        return base64_encode("Salted__" . $salt . $ciphertext_raw);
```

Comment: The openssl statement uses a key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey()`) which is not applied in the PHP code.

Comment: how do I apply this?

Comment: You need an implementation for PHP, check the web. The ciphertext generated with the openssl statement must be Base64 decoded, then it consists of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__` followed by the 8 bytes salt and the actual ciphertext. `EVP_BytesTokey()` expects as input a password (`$key`), the salt, an iteration count (1) and a digest (MD5). Create a (32 + 16) bytes output and use the first 32 bytes as key, the following 16 bytes as IV. With key and IV the ciphertext can be decrypted.

Comment: will this work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66037686/implement-php-open-ssl-decrypt-aes-256-cbc-as-cryptojs ? I need to use md5

Comment: @Topaco see my update

Comment: @Topaco I got the decrypt to work with the link you gave. thanks. just trying to figure out to to make encrypt work with just the passphrase

Comment: @Topaco working now thanks

Comment: Since the random salt always results in different ciphertexts, the easiest test for OpenSSL compatibility is to decrypt with OpenSSL. The code for encryption posted in your update section can be _successfully_ decrypted with OpenSSL on my machine (at least when the first `return` statement is removed). Why do you think the implementation does not work and how did you perform your test?

Comment: its working, i didn't see the hidden 1st return statement, haha

Answer (score 3):

The following code is a full running example that uses the "EVP_BytesToKey" key derivation as commented by @Topaco.

Kindly note that this kind of key derivation is **UNSECURE** as it uses the **broken MD5 algorithm** and an iteration count of only 1. Please **use the code only for migration purpose**, thanks.

This is a possible output [as there are random elements your output will differ]:

```
AES CBC 256 String encryption with passphrase

# # # SECURITY WARNING: This code is provided for achieve    # # #
# # # compatibility between different programming languages. # # #
# # # It is not necessarily fully secure.                    # # #
# # # Its security depends on the complexity and length      # # #
# # # of the password, because of only one iteration and     # # #
# # # the use of MD5.                                        # # #
# # # DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION                     # # #

passphrase: my secret passphrase

* * * Encryption * * *
ciphertext: U2FsdGVkX1/+hqfCdNaZ36kZzPzwvFXkr4nEySMEgdVdPnPrGUj2Gi1t2pspAH2WHVEVgKHKWfR2Gc0sKnTlLg==
output is (Base64) ciphertext

* * * Decryption * * *
passphrase: my secret passphrase
ciphertext (Base64): U2FsdGVkX19rV+JOoeF72K54jlyJ47tNEsMjih7gDnFUysZFaw+WnYTB5L/hc2+rssFj1hXw3N8kkikHwClB2w==
input is (Base64) ciphertext
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

code:

```
<?php
// source: https://github.com/blocktrail/cryptojs-aes-php/blob/master/src/CryptoJSAES.php
// author: BlockTrail
function aesCbcPassphraseEncryptToBase64($passphrase, $data, $salt = null) {
    $salt = $salt ?: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
    list($key, $iv) = evpkdf($passphrase, $salt);
    $ct = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
    return encode($ct, $salt);
}

function aesCbcPassphraseDecryptFromBase64($passphrase, $base64) {
    list($ct, $salt) = decode($base64);
    list($key, $iv) = evpkdf($passphrase, $salt);
    $data = openssl_decrypt($ct, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
    return $data;
}

function evpkdf($passphrase, $salt) {
    $salted = '';
    $dx = '';
    while (strlen($salted) < 48) {
        $dx = md5($dx . $passphrase . $salt, true);
        $salted .= $dx;
    }
    $key = substr($salted, 0, 32);
    $iv = substr($salted, 32, 16);
    return [$key, $iv];
}

function decode($base64) {
    $data = base64_decode($base64);
    if (substr($data, 0, 8) !== "Salted__") {
        return "";
    }
    $salt = substr($data, 8, 8);
    $ct = substr($data, 16);
    return [$ct, $salt];
}

function encode($ct, $salt) {
    return base64_encode("Salted__" . $salt . $ct);
}

echo 'AES CBC 256 String encryption with passphrase' . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL . '# # # SECURITY WARNING: This code is provided for achieve    # # #' . PHP_EOL;
echo '# # # compatibility between different programming languages. # # #' . PHP_EOL;
echo '# # # It is not necessarily fully secure.                    # # #' . PHP_EOL;
echo '# # # Its security depends on the complexity and length      # # #' . PHP_EOL;
echo '# # # of the password, because of only one iteration and     # # #' . PHP_EOL;
echo '# # # the use of MD5.                                        # # #' . PHP_EOL;
echo '# # # DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION                     # # #' . PHP_EOL;

$plaintext = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$passphrase = 'my secret passphrase';
echo PHP_EOL . 'passphrase: ' . $passphrase . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL . '* * * Encryption * * *' . PHP_EOL;
$ciphertextBase64 = aesCbcPassphraseEncryptToBase64($passphrase, $plaintext);
echo 'ciphertext (Base64): ' . $ciphertextBase64 . PHP_EOL;
echo 'output is (Base64) ciphertext' . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL . '* * * Decryption * * *' . PHP_EOL;
$decryptionPassphrase = $passphrase;
$ciphertextDecryptionBase64 = $ciphertextBase64;
echo 'decryptionPassphrase: ' . $decryptionPassphrase . PHP_EOL;
echo 'ciphertext (Base64): ' . $ciphertextDecryptionBase64 . PHP_EOL;
echo 'input is (Base64) ciphertext' . PHP_EOL;
$decryptedtext = aesCbcPassphraseDecryptFromBase64($decryptionPassphrase, $ciphertextDecryptionBase64);
echo 'plaintext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, when trying to encrypt a string that would be later decoded in JS with 

    bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(mystring,secretKey);
    decrypt = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8) 

originally encoded in JS with


    CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(mystring,secretKey).toString();